# Is there a way to offset the 2nd interval to start 500ms after the 1st one?

Tags: javascript, function

1ST interval (is okay with its timing)

```
startBlinking();
    function RstartWalking() {
        setInterval(function() {
            walk();
        }, 1000);
    }
    function walk() {
        Rlegy = Rlegy - 7;
      Rinvy = Rinvy - 7;
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (Rlegy > Rlegy - 6) {
                Rlegy = Rlegy + 7
              Rinvy = Rinvy +7
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

2ND interval that i need to start 500ms later than the 1st

```
RstartWalking();
function LstartWalking() {
    setInterval(function() {
        Lwalk();
    }, 1000);
}
function Lwalk() {
    Llegy = Llegy - 7;
  Linvy = Linvy - 7
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (Llegy > Llegy - 6) {
            Llegy = Llegy + 7
          Linvy = Linvy +7
        }
    }, 500);
}
LstartWalking();
```

I basically need the 2nd interval to start 500ms after the 1st
(if you are interested in viewing the entire code, here it is
https://editor.p5js.org/LttntLark/sketches/JBSg2zIfEf)

Comment: `setTimeout(() => LstartWalking(), 500);`

Comment: where do i put that line?

Comment: You would replace your existing call to LstartWalking with the timeout, so it happens 500ms later.

Comment: thank you! This helped alot!

Comment: Do you want them to alternate every 500ms?
You can either use a flag to know which part of the code to run within a function an call it again with 500ms delay, or have two functions calling each other after running their individual code - with 500ms delay.
With flag: `var first=true;
function one() { if(first) { /* do stuff */ } else { /* do other stuff */ }; first=!first;
setTimeout(one, 500); };
one();`,
Two functions: `function a() { /* do stuff */; setTimeout(b, 500); };
function b() { /* do (other) stuff */; setTimeout(a, 500); };
a();`.